# MySQL procedure keeps inserting replicated fields

Tags: mysql

This keeps inserting already existing fields although it shouldn't.

```
BEGIN 

INSERT INTO ohrm_attendance_raw_data (punch_time, device_id, card_number)
SELECT punch_time, device_id, card_number
FROM ohrm_attendance_master
WHERE  ohrm_attendance_master.punch_time >= DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM ohrm_attendance_record WHERE ohrm_attendance_record.punch_in_user_time = ohrm_attendance_master.punch_time) 
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM ohrm_attendance_record WHERE ohrm_attendance_record.punch_out_user_time = punch_time);

end
```

Comment: Your SQL statement is depending on  two conditions. I would test the conditions to find where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your field `punch_time` is datetime type or something like that... so I think your problem is that you are comparing two dates... and what's the problem with that?, that MySQL and other RDBMS compare that including hour, minutes, seconds and miliseconds... so it can make that the comparison be false... You can trunc the date or give it some format:

With `DATE` function:

```
BEGIN 

    INSERT INTO ohrm_attendance_raw_data (punch_time, device_id, card_number)
    SELECT punch_time, device_id, card_number
    FROM ohrm_attendance_master
    WHERE  ohrm_attendance_master.punch_time >= DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM ohrm_attendance_record WHERE DATE(ohrm_attendance_record.punch_in_user_time) = DATE(ohrm_attendance_master.punch_time)) 
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM ohrm_attendance_record WHERE DATE(ohrm_attendance_record.punch_out_user_time) = DATE(punch_time));
END
```

With `DATE_FORMAT` function:

```
BEGIN 

    INSERT INTO ohrm_attendance_raw_data (punch_time, device_id, card_number)
    SELECT punch_time, device_id, card_number
    FROM ohrm_attendance_master
    WHERE  ohrm_attendance_master.punch_time >= DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM ohrm_attendance_record WHERE DATE_FORMAT(ohrm_attendance_record.punch_in_user_time, '%d-%b-%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(ohrm_attendance_master.punch_time, '%d-%b-%Y')) 
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM ohrm_attendance_record WHERE DATE_FORMAT(ohrm_attendance_record.punch_out_user_time, '%d-%b-%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(punch_time,'%d-%b-%Y'));
END
```